# Sed error: bad flag in substitute command: 'U'

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm new in bash script and trying to replace some words in my file using sed. Following is the bash I use in my script:

```
sed -i '' "s/<pre>.*<\/pre>/<pre>($NEWNAME) $MD5<\/pre>/"~/Desktop/replace.html
```

And  I got error message saying: `bad flag in substitute command: 'U'`. I use double quote because I need to put variables in.

My environment is Mac.

======================================

1.Turns out I forgot to leave a space between replace string and file name. Which led to the result always showing: `bad flag in substitute command: '~'`. It works now.

2.The reason is I used `MD5=$(md5 path)` to create MD5 value which gets the reault of `MD5 (path) *****`, and the path contains `/` which breaks the regex. After changing `MD5=$(md5 -q path)`, it will be ok.

Comment: Don't use text processing tools to edit HTML. Use a tool designed for working with HTML.

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks. But I have to upload files and change the md5 value in the HTML using the shell script. Do you have some better idea for this?

Comment: Use a language that supports editing HTML, such as Perl, Python, PHP, Ruby, ...

Comment: @TomFenech My html is very simple and I only need to change a md5 value in it. Learning a new language to support this is a burden for me now. But I will try later. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most likely your `$NEWNAME` variable has a forward slash in it, which is being used as regex delimiter in `sed`. Try this `sed` with an **alternate delimiter** e.g. `~`:

```
sed -i '' "s~<pre>.*</pre>~<pre>($NEWNAME) $MD5</pre>~" ~/Desktop/replace.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I echo these variables and find `MD5` get forward slash. But using alternate delimiter like `~` will get similar mistake: `bad flag in substitute command: '~'`

Comment: You can also use control chars as sed delimiter e.g. `sed -i '' "s^A<pre>.*</pre>^A<pre>($NEWNAME) $MD5</pre>^A"` where `^A` is typed by pressing `control-V-A` together.

Comment: OK, to be honest, this is the first time I come to the concept of alternate delimiter. So thanks a lot. I will keep trying.

Comment: No need to keep trying. Reason is simple that your variable cannot have unescaped regex delimiter you're using. Hence the need to use an alternate delimiter like a control character as I posted in previous comment. Or else use some other tool like awk